# Direct Access Configured on Single Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

The requirements to configure the Direct Access feature in Windows Server 2008R2 is listed here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382305(WS.10).aspx

However, it is not clear as to whether all of the required components needed for configuring Direct Access can reside on a single physical server.

Can anyone verify whether all of the server requirements can reside on a single machine?

For example, can the Direct Access server be on the same machine that runs the Domain Name System, Active Directory, IIS etc..?

Answer (score 1):

I would say no.  DA requires you to have the server in a DMZ environment, which is not the most secure place to have your AD infrastructure.  If you have a decent server, use VMware Server or Hyper-V to create separate servers.